# Embedded Twitter timeline in PhoneGap 3.1.0 application

Tags: twitter, cordova

I have an issue with integrating Twitter timeline with PhoneGap 3.1.0 application (iOS version)

1) I have generated a new PhoneGap 3.1.0 application

2) Have added iOS version

3) I have generated a timeline widget in Twitter

4) Have pasted the code from Twitter widget into the page:

**index.html**:

```
<a class="twitter-timeline" href="https://twitter.com/bill_hallam" data-widget-id="399136844954087424">Tweets by @bill_hallam</a>
<script>!function(d,s,id){var js,fjs=d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0],p=/^http:/.test(d.location)?'http':'https';if(!d.getElementById(id)){js=d.createElement(s);js.id=id;js.src=p+"://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js";fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js,fjs);}}(document,"script","twitter-wjs");</script>
```

5) Have whitelisted twitter domains:

**config.xml**:

```
<access origin="https://twitter.com" subdomains="true" />
<access origin="http://twitter.com" subdomains="true" />
<access origin="http://platform.twitter.com" />
<access origin="https://platform.twitter.com" />
<access origin="https://cdn.syndication.twimg.com" />
<access origin="http://cdn.syndication.twimg.com" />
```

6) Started the iOS emulator from Xcode

**Result:** The page is blank. Safari Develop console shows that twitter `<iframe>` tag is embedded in the page. All js/css files retrieved successfully. None if them was blacklisted.

Does anyone have succesfull experience integrating Twitter timeline into PhoneGap 3.1 app?

Comment: Does it work in a regular html page in a regular browser? What if you just allow everything in the whitelist to make sure you're not missing a domain?

Comment: @MBillau, as you proposed I have added * to the whitespace list but the result is the same. In regular browser the html page opens with timeline displayed

Comment: Is there any way you can host the twitter timeline page on a server, and then open that page with the native mobile browser (safari)? This would help us determine if the problem is with the cordova wrapper or "higher up."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have finally figured out a way to do that.
Unfortunately at the moment the only solution I have found is using an InAppBrowser plugin.
But it works for both - iOS and Android versions.

The detailed description is [here](https://github.com/k-rudy/phonegap-twitter-timeline)

I have created a small public page, that functions as a service.

Answer (score 8):

#### Update Nov 29 2016

This is most probably not the issue the OP faced back then, but if anyone faces the same issue these days (using Cordova 6.4.0, as of Nov 29 2016), the answer is to add:

```
<allow-navigation href="about:*" />
```

to your `config.xml`.

This is required to be able to open the `about:blank` URL initially used by the `iframe` set up by the Twitter timeline widget.

Comment: I can't thank you enough! You saved me tons of trouble.